# Rails select options only seem to send 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I am trying to use select options in rails

```
<%= f.select :category, options_for_select(["Select One", "Cell", "Work", "Office", "Home", "Other"],[1,2,3,4,5,6]) %>
```

Params
       def story_params
       params.require(:story).permit(:title, :body, :user_id, :category)

but the database table only seems to get "0" whenever my post is submitted, why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add like this instead

```
<%= f.select :category, options_for_select([["Select One", 1], ["Cell", 2], ["Work", 3], ["Office", 4], ["Home", 5], ["Other", 6]]) %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I get the error "wrong number of arguments (given 6, expected 1..2)" when I do that

Comment: @Jay You might not have given outer square brackets []

Comment: Try copy pasting my answer instead, as @Sajin said you might have missed the outer [].

Comment: Okay, that works, can't believe I overlooked that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

options_for_select  accept key and value in nested array format if you didn't pass value it will take key as value

so, you need to pass as key,value pair like `[["Select One", 1],["Cell", 2]..etc]`

For more reference view [this](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)